# How do I specify output directory when using NME 3.5.3

Tags: haxe, nme

I have just upgraded NME to 3.5.3, and it seems like the compiled files always end up in a directory called "bin" relative to the main source file. In my nmml file I have a line like this:

```
 <set name="BUILD_DIR" value="/path/to/output/dir" />
```

And that line specified where the output files ended up in previous versions of NME. How is it done now? The only reference documentation I have found on how .nmml files should be written is at http://www.nme.io/developers/documentation-old/nmml-project-files/ And since the url says `documentation-old` I suspect it is not current anymore. Is there an up-to-date version of that documentation?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This seems to have been fixed in version 3.5.4